# Schema name resolution for a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

According to books online (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915(v=sql.105).aspx) we have:

In SQL Server, if the current schema contains a procedure with the specified name, that procedure is returned. If a nonqualified stored procedure is specified, the Database Engine searches for the procedure in the following order:

•   The sys schema of the current database.

•   The caller's default schema if executed in a batch or in dynamic SQL; or, **if the non-qualified procedure name appears inside the body of another procedure definition, the schema containing this other procedure is searched next.**

•   The dbo schema in the current database.

I tried testing the case with a stored procedure Proc1 which calls proc2. I define them in the same schema, but call proc2 without the schema name. It doesn't work, so what does the second part of item two on the list above mean?

```
Use AdventureWorks
GO

CREATE SCHEMA MySchema
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE MySchema.PROC2
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT 1
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE MySchema.PROC1
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT 2
        -- calling proc2 without schema name
        -- expecting it will work, since proc1 and proc2 are in same schema
        EXEC PROC2
END

GO

--calling proc1 (my default schema is dbo)
--Could not find stored procedure 'PROC2'.
EXEC MySchema.PROC1
```

I know best practice is to always use the schema name - I'm just curious what they mean by the second item. I've tested this on version 2016.

Answer (score 1):

The page you have linked to is the documentation for a specific system stored procedure. Its meaning is limited to what this stored procedure does.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySchema.PROC1
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT 2
        -- calling proc2 without schema name
        -- expecting it will work, since proc1 and proc2 are in same schema
        EXEC sp_stored_procedures 'PROC2'
END
```

Produces 2 result sets - the first contains `2`, the second contains information about the `MySchema.PROC2` stored procedure.

Comment: Sorry the link is wrong. Here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915(v=sql.105).aspx

If a nonqualified user-defined stored procedure is specified, the Database Engine searches for the procedure in the following order:

The sys schema of the current database.

The caller's default schema if executed in a batch or in dynamic SQL. Or, if the nonqualified procedure name appears inside the body of another procedure definition, the schema containing this other procedure is searched next. For more information about default schemas, see User-Schema Separation.

Comment: This question is still open